# Twig строку в переменную

Tags: twig

необходимо вывести переменную `{{block_main_title_setting}}`
в коде в цикле переменная выводится так: `{{'block_'~blockId~'_title_setting'}}`
где blockId = main

но почему-то вместо значение переменной выводится block_main_title_setting

как сделать, чтобы выводилось именно значение. а не текст переменной?

вот полный код:

```
{% for section in sections_setting|split(',') %}
    {%set blockId = section|split(':')[0]|slice(0, -5)%}

    <div class="fields_row">
        <label for="block_{{blockId}}_title_setting">Заголовок блока: {{section|split(':')[1]}}</label>
        <input type="text" id="block_{{blockId}}_title_setting" data-key="block_{{blockId}}_title_setting" value="{{'block_'~blockId~'_title_setting'}}" placeholder="Заголовок блока:" />
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

решил вопрос сам:
    {{attribute(*context, 'block*'~blockId~'_title_setting')}}

только _context а не context (в сообщении почему-то убирается подчеркивание)